# Inverse map theorem for function $T:\mathbb{R}^{n}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^{n}$

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Let $T:\mathbb{R}^{n}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^{n}$ be a continuously differentiable function such that  $T'$ is an invertible linear transformation for every $x\in\mathbb{R}^{n}.$ Then we must  have

$A.$ $T$ is an open map i.e. maps open set to open set.

$B.$ $T$ is an one one  map.

$C.$ $T$ is locally one one.

$D.$ $T$ is an onto map.

I tried it as by Inverse map theorem $T$ is locally one-one and counterexample is $f(x,y)=(e^{x}\cos y,e^{x}\sin y)$ for one one. How to solve option $A$ and $D ?$ as inverse map theorem says that $T$ map an open set around the point to an open set. How is it open map? What about onto? Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your example shows that $D$ is incorrect.

Comment: ok so it remains only option $A$?